# I am a beginner in python, and I would like to ask how to solve the error: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'?

Tags: python-3.x

```
list = []
jim = 70
list.append('Jim')
parry = 36
list.append('parry')
ada = 68
list.append('ada')
jevon = 25
list.append('jevon')
samuel = 94
list.append('samuel')
bryant = 81
list.append('bryant')
sia = 12
list.append('sia')
print(list)

for s in list:
    if s>90:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{s} got the gold medal award.")
    elif s>80:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{s} got the silver medal award.")
    elif s>70:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{s} got the bronze medal award.")
    elif s>=60:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{s} has passed the exam.")
    elif s<60:
        print(f"{s} I am sorry to inform that you have failed the exam.")
```

Comment: Your `elif s<60:` test can simply be `else:`

Answer (score 1):

Your list contains the *strings* `['Jim', 'parry', 'ada', ...]`.  These strings have no relations to the *variables* that share the same names.  So you end up checking for conditions like `'Jim' > 90`, which makes no sense.  You probably want to use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) here.  For example:

```
grades = {
    'Jim': 70,
    'Parry': 36,
    'Ada': 68,
    'Jevon': 25,
    'Samuel': 94,
    'Bryant': 81,
    'Sia': 12,
}
print(grades)

for name, grade in grades.items():
    if grade > 90:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{name} got the gold medal award.")
    elif grade > 80:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{name} got the silver medal award.")
    elif grade > 70:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{name} got the bronze medal award.")
    elif grade > =60:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{name} has passed the exam.")
    elif grade < 60:
        print(f"{name} I am sorry to inform that you have failed the exam.")
```

Also just a note: You shouldn't name a variable `list`, because it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) type.  Same for all of the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, it has definitely simplified my code, and solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

*P.S. You probably want the first element to be `jim` instead of `Jim`*

*You will also want to change the name of `list` because it will override(shadow) the python stantard type `list`*

In your case, you probably want the following:

```py
for i in lst:
    s = eval(i)
    if s>90:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{i} got the gold medal award.")
    elif s>80:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{i} got the silver medal award.")
    elif s>70:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{i} got the bronze medal award.")
    elif s>=60:
        print(f"Congratulations! \n{i} has passed the exam.")
    elif s<60:
        print(f"{i} I am sorry to inform that you have failed the exam.")
```

It will look for the proper variables in current scope.

Output:

```
['jim', 'parry', 'ada', 'jevon', 'samuel', 'bryant', 'sia']
Congratulations! 
jim has passed the exam.
parry I am sorry to inform that you have failed the exam.
Congratulations! 
ada has passed the exam.
jevon I am sorry to inform that you have failed the exam.
Congratulations! 
samuel got the gold medal award.
Congratulations! 
bryant got the silver medal award.
sia I am sorry to inform that you have failed the exam.
```

The exception is because(not like comparing `char` and `int` in C/C++, which compares ASCII codes) comparing strings to integers make no sense.

Comment: Promoting the use of `eval` here, when it's completely unnecessary, is a bad idea imo.

Comment: It's... a good idea when you don't want to use dictionaries(e.g. loading the variables from an external module). Yes, it can cause security problems and excess memory usage, but... I believe this is a good idea. E.g. `from module.grades import *` and using `eval(i)` here. It can be very convenient in many cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree but the broader point is that Python coders asking this kind of question are generally new to programming, do not really understand variables and values, and guiding them to `eval` or `exec` is almost always the wrong advice. They would be better served by an answer using dicts and/or lists.